# Unable to start Openssh in Windows

Tags: windows-7, cmd, openssh

This is what i get every time i run sshd in cmd.

```
C:\Program Files\OpenSSH\usr\sbin>sshd -d -d -d
debug2: read_server_config: filename /etc/sshd_config
debug1: sshd version OpenSSH_3.8.1p1
debug3: Not a RSA1 key file /etc/ssh_host_rsa_key.
debug1: read PEM private key done: type RSA
debug1: private host key: #0 type 1 RSA
debug3: Not a RSA1 key file /etc/ssh_host_dsa_key.
debug1: read PEM private key done: type DSA
debug1: private host key: #1 type 2 DSA
debug1: Bind to port 22 on 0.0.0.0.
Server listening on 0.0.0.0 port 22.
```

I'm new to ssh client thing and i'm using this in a project i'm doing..
I got the method of doin this in http://www.worldgoneweb.com/2011/installing-openssh-on-windows-7/
I could not change the permissions using chmod and chown as shown in that forum.
Can anyone please help me in debugging this ?!
and moreover when i use
"net start openssh"
I get a "system error 5 has occurred. Access denied "

Comment: Debugging what? The SSHD server has started and is listening at port 22. The 'access denied' means you need administrator privilege to start it as a service.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just got this going myself following the same article. I got the "system error 5" message initially too.

Solution: Run cmd.exe as administrator by right clicking on it and choosing "Run as administrator"

Comment: Nice working: I think , now all windows program should run as admin. :)